# How do I delete items from dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using dynamodb resource (boto3) to delete records from 2 tables. Below is my query.

```
results = dynamodb.batch_write_item(
        RequestItems=[
            {
                'user_tale': {
                    'DeleteRequest': {
                        "Key": {
                            'id': id
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                'user_detail': {
                    'DeleteRequest': {
                        "Key": {
                            'id': id
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    )
```

I am getting validation error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter RequestItems, value: [{'user_tale': {'DeleteRequest': {'Key': {'id': '156242a5-f57c-4b76-a772-a0d5eb3806b7'}}}}, {'user_detail': {'DeleteRequest': {'Key': {'id': '156242a5-f57c-4b76-a772-a0d5eb3806b7'}}}}], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
```

is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for `RequestItems`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.batch_write_item) says:

> A map of one or more table names and, for each table, a list of operations to be performed

```py
response = client.batch_write_item(
    RequestItems={
        'tablename': [
            {
                'DeleteRequest': {
                    'Key': {
                        'string': {
```

Your code is going straight to the List:

```py
results = dynamodb.batch_write_item(
        RequestItems=[
            {
```

Therefore, add the tablename as the first element of the Dictionary, and then include the List.

Comment: Thanks. How can I define the table name in this case?

Comment: Updated the answer. It seems that the dictionary contains table names, with the values being set to the List of items to delete.